# Haskell .hs files turning into .hi files?

Tags: haskell

I just installed an application that has a number of .hs Haskell files
https://github.com/tidalcycles/Tidal/tree/master/src/Sound/Tidal

After installation via cabal, all of the .hs files are .hi files. Is this something that cabal does to the files?

Comment: These are "interface files". These store the data that another module that depends on the module needs to know.

Comment: The compiler usually processes each .hs source file and produces two binary files: .hi ("Haskell interface", containing type info, code to inline elsewhere, and other data) and .o (object file with the machine code).

Comment: The hs files should still exist. They shouldn't be deleted or otherwise "replaced".  The hi files should simply coexist.